# Books similar to Fifty Challenging Problems in Probability with Solutions by Frederick Mosteller

Tags: probability, reference-request, book-recommendation

I find the book [Fifty Challenging Problems in Probability with Solutions by Frederick Mosteller](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486653552).

I would like to solve more probability problems whose levels are similar to book above. 
Does anyone have good suggestions?

Comment: bounty of 50 would have been more than enough to get a very good answer, but good that you're generous :)

Comment: Haha thanks for your compliment. Why don't you have a try? The 300 bounty might be yours....

Comment: I'll leave a comment if I think of something. Feels wrong to get reputation (especially so much) for a not mathematical answer, but that's just me.

Answer (score 5):

The closest to Mosteller's book is probably Yaglom's *[Challenging Mathematical Problems With Elementary Solutions: Combinatorial Analysis and Probability Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486655369)*. It was published around the same time, the problems have a similar flavor, and it doesn't require any knowledge of measure theory.

You may also be interested in Patrick's *[Intermediate Counting and Probability](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0083CIHAM)*, as well as in the chapter "Combinatorics and Probability" of Andreescu's *[Putnam and Beyond](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3319589865)*.

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest the *"Problems and solutions"* section of the *Americal Matematical Monthly* journal. Quite frequently they suggest problems related to probability and statistics. According to me sometimes they have the same flavour as problems from the Mosteller's and Yaglom's book.

Don't know whether there exists a separate archive of the *"Problems and solutions"* section. Yet, most of the issues are available here https://www.jstor.org/journal/amermathmont.

There is one book with the collection of problems from SIAM: *Murray S. Klamkin - Problems in applied mathematics: selections from SIAM review-Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics (1987)* https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611971729. It has the probability chapter, including some problems from *Americal Matematical Monthly*. Moreover, in some problems not related to probability, you can find unexpected comments related to probability.

Comment: I am not sure about the 'Problem and solution; from American Mathematical Monthly as those questions are meant to be very difficult.

Comment: Yes indeed, they can be difficult. But there are also simple problems (simple if you make a smart guess).

Comment: But need to find right? Not all problems in the problem and solution section are about probability.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Need to find. As i wrote, don't know whether an archive with the collection of problems from 'Problem and solution' exists.